# Нужен ли CSRF для Laravel, использующегося только как REST API

Tags: laravel, rest, безопасность, oauth, csrf

Есть backend на Laravel. Laravel - только для REST.
В документации к пакету Sanctum нашёл, как получают CSRF для SPA(Single Page Application), если Laravel полностью на REST API. Там была достаточно странная реализация авторизации для SPA, которая кидала сессию рядом с CSRF, и мне показалась костыльной и не правильной. Я решил полностью убрать всё, что связано с сессиями. Поэтому перешёл на Passport. И не понимаю, нужен ли мне CSRF токен? Ведь все POST запросы всё равно будут производится только для авторизованных пользователей через заголовок `Authorization: Bearer access_token` access_token лежит в локальном хранилище
И никаких авторизаций при помощи cookies и быть не может. А это значит, что пропадает вся необходимость защиты от CSRF. Я прав?

Comment: Да прав, CSRF  не нужен в REST API, все route создавайте на файлу routes/api.php

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Посмотрите вначале класс RouteServiceProvider - там для api используется группа мидлварей "api", а для web - web. Затем смотрите класс Kernel - там перечислено, что входит в группу мидлварей. CSRF проверяется в VerifyCsrfToken, который входит только в web - это явно прописано в Kernel

Comment: Хмм, помню. как у меня выскакивала 419 при отправке запроса к api